# Memory leak when using NetFwTypeLib in .Net Core 3.1

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-core-3.1, windows-firewall-api

I tracked down a memory leak in this IDS/IPS traffic monitor console app I've been working on. I thought it was entity framework, turns out it's the firewall code. The following code worked perfectly fine in .net 4.6.2 and it works mostly fine in .net core. However, it has a memory leak (specifically the second `firewallRule` line):

```
INetFwPolicy2 firewallPolicy = (INetFwPolicy2)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("HNetCfg.FwPolicy2"));
INetFwRule firewallRule = firewallPolicy.Rules.OfType<INetFwRule>().Where(x => x.Name == fwRuleName).FirstOrDefault();
```

I have to restart the app daily as it will burn through as much memory as I let it. I've seen it as high as 12GB when it should be running around 35MB. It only takes a day or so to get that high too. So basically each call to `firewallRule` is eating ~5MB-10MB. Seems crazy a single or null record would use up that much memory.

I believe it's that `firewallRule` line because I've literally commented out every other line in the method that's being called (and the app for that matter), and when I finally comment out that line, the leak stops. Please let me know if my logic is flawed.

If you want to test it, you have to make a reference to `NetFwTypeLib` to make that code work.

Does anyone know why this is happening and how to remedy it?

**Update:**

Here is the original code for those that believe I haven't commented it all out:

```
public static void FirewallSetup(string ip, string countryCode, bool isIpsString)
        {

        //    FirewallControl fwCtrl = new FirewallControl();
        //    fwCtrl.Block(ip, countryCode, isIpsString);
        //}

        //private void Block(string ip, string countryCode, bool isIpsString)
        //{
            var remoteAddresses = "*";
            string fwRuleName;
            bool createNewFwRule = false;

            //var fwRuleSuffix = SQLControl.GetFirewallRuleSuffix(countryCode).ToString();
            //if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(fwRuleSuffix) || fwRuleSuffix == "0")
            //{
                fwRuleName = fwRuleNamePrefix + countryCode;
            //}
            //else
            //{
            //    fwRuleName = fwRuleNamePrefix + countryCode + fwRuleSuffix;
            //}

            INetFwPolicy2 firewallPolicy = (INetFwPolicy2)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("HNetCfg.FwPolicy2"));
            INetFwRule firewallRule = firewallPolicy.Rules.OfType<INetFwRule>().Where(x => x.Name == fwRuleName).FirstOrDefault();

            //if (firewallRule == null)
            //{
            //    createNewFwRule = true;
            //}
            //else
            //{
            //    //We need the following for creating the remoteAddresses string below
            //    //but, also need to count as Windows has a 5000 ip limit per rule
            //    remoteAddresses = firewallRule.RemoteAddresses;
            //    string[] aRemoteAddresses = remoteAddresses.Split(",");
            //    int remoteAddressesCount = aRemoteAddresses.Length;
            //    //Log.Debug(">>>Firewall remote addresses scope=" + remoteAddresses);
            //    Log.Warning(">>>" + fwRuleName + " Firewall remote addresses count:" + remoteAddressesCount);

            //    //5000 would be 0 to 4999 I think?
            //    if (remoteAddressesCount >= 4999)
            //    {
            //        //If remote ip scope is 5000, create a new fw rule
            //        var newFwRuleNameSuffix = SQLControl.GetNewFirewallRuleSuffix(countryCode).ToString();
            //        fwRuleName = fwRuleNamePrefix + countryCode + newFwRuleNameSuffix;

            //        createNewFwRule = true;
            //    }
            //}

            //If necessary, we create a new rule
            //TODO: Create another method for this?
            //if (createNewFwRule)
            //{
            //    firewallRule = (INetFwRule)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("HNetCfg.FWRule"));
            //    firewallRule.Name = fwRuleName;
            //    firewallPolicy.Rules.Add(firewallRule);
            //    firewallRule.Description = "Block inbound traffic from " + countryCode;
            //    firewallRule.Profiles = (int)NET_FW_PROFILE_TYPE2_.NET_FW_PROFILE2_ALL;
            //    firewallRule.Protocol = (int)NET_FW_IP_PROTOCOL_.NET_FW_IP_PROTOCOL_TCP;
            //    firewallRule.Direction = NET_FW_RULE_DIRECTION_.NET_FW_RULE_DIR_IN;
            //    firewallRule.Action = NET_FW_ACTION_.NET_FW_ACTION_BLOCK;
            //    firewallRule.Enabled = true;
            //    //firewallRule.RemoteAddresses = ip;
            //    //firewallPolicy.Rules.Add(firewallRule); //throws error and not needed anyway
            //    //firewallRule.LocalPorts = "4000";
            //    //firewallRule.Grouping = "@firewallapi.dll,-23255";
            //    //firewallRule.Profiles = firewallPolicy.CurrentProfileTypes;
            //}

            //if (isIpsString || remoteAddresses == "*")
            //{
            //    firewallRule.RemoteAddresses = ip;
            //}
            //else
            //{
            //    firewallRule.RemoteAddresses = remoteAddresses + "," + ip;
            //}
        }
```

In production, it simply executes this method "as is" and just eats memory. Again, it is specific to .Net Core as I ran this same code in .Net 4.6.1 (un-commented) for more than a year without issue.

Now that I think about it and have commented it out, I can also put it through some loop and troubleshoot it here internally. It's a race...

The server it's currently running on is Windows Server 2016.

**Update 2:** It's reproducible in Windows 10 also. Here is a the entire code to reproduce the error:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using NetFwTypeLib;

namespace FirewallLeakTesterCore
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int count = 0;
            while (count < 1000)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(count += 1);
                INetFwPolicy2 firewallPolicy = (INetFwPolicy2)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("HNetCfg.FwPolicy2"));
                INetFwRule firewallRule = firewallPolicy.Rules.OfType<INetFwRule>().Where(x => x.Name == "firewallRuleName").FirstOrDefault();

            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the result:

Visual Studio Diagnostic Tools:

[image: Visual Studio Diagnostic Tools]

Seems like a Microsoft bug? I guess I'll try and tackle one of these memory profilers, but even if I discover the issue, what can I do? This is a basic call to a basic windows library which I think is why some people in the comments are missing the point.

I'm not asking for anyone to memory profile my app or track down the issue (and never was... I've already done that). I'm asking for alternate solutions. Is there possibly a structure or linq issue or other statement entirely I can use?

If you want to leave the question closed, then so be it, but I have a hard time believing no one else is going to run into this.

Comment: Why not use a Memory Profiler (e.g. [this](https://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-memory-profiler/) or [this](https://www.jetbrains.com/dotmemory/)) to check whether your assumption is correct?

Comment: Where does `NetFwTypeLib` come from?

Comment: You are asking us to guess where a memory leak is in an application we cant see, in libraries we don't know about

Comment: @UweKeim I don't have money for those pay to play products. Furthermore, it's hard to test because it's really only apparent in production (because it's a traffic monitor and filtering out internal ips and especially not blocking them). I found an old memory profiler (clr profiler.exe from Microsoft) that I was going to try, but haven't put the time in yet. `NetFwTypeLib` comes from the windows firewall. I'm also not sure why you edited out the .net core 3.1 in the title when it's specific to .net core and exact code worked fine in .net 4.6.1.

Comment: @MichaelRandall No I'm not. It's a standard windows firewall library. It exists on your machine too, assuming it's windows.

Comment: They have free trial versions (14 days and 5 days).

Comment: Presumably you had to comment out more than that single line: you also had to change the code which uses `firewallRule`? My guess is the leak is in code which uses `firewallRule`, which we can't see.

Comment: @canton7 No, it's all commented out. Wait, I'll add the code...

Comment: Btw, PerfView is free, standalone, and can be used to analyse heap memory.

Comment: If possible, try if it helps to make `firewallPolicy` a global singleton object. Who knows if it might lack proper `Dispose` behaviour, e.g. it might claim resources from Windows that are then never freed. We are talking COM Interop after all...

Comment: @PeterB Excellent, thanks! I'll give it a try. This is more the type of answer I was looking for since I have no skills in memory profile troubleshooting. Thanks much!

Comment: It is worth playing around with e.g. PerfView. It doesn't take much learning (only a few hours) to get skilled enough to get some decent results out of it, and that's much less than you'll waste trying to avoid learning how to use a profiler

Comment: @canton7 Awesome, I'll give it a try. I'm currently trying to use the Memory Usage>Take Snapshot>View Heap in VS2019, but not getting far (probably going to go read a tutorial). I'm going to check out Perfview before I proceed any further with this. Thanks for the recommendation.

Comment: I have downgraded my project back to .Net Framework 4.6.1. However, for those that want to follow this issue (as it doesn't seem to be indexing in Google and others with the obvious keywords): https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/32747

Answer (score 1):

I see a lot of comments in regards to your memory profiling and not a lot about addressing your problem... Here is an article you could use to test for memory leaks from JetBrains https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2018/10/04/unit-testing-memory-leaks-using-dotmemory-unit/

As to your problem, I guess you might have a look at  [Marshal.ReleaseComObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.releasecomobject?view=net-6.0)

I would release any COM call with something like this:

```
if (_netFwPolicy is not null && OperatingSystem.IsWindows())
{
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(_netFwPolicy);
}
```

But what you really need to consider is wrapping the instances in a class that handles IDispose, this way any foreach will free the item as well, looping over the items in your policy will become an issue when used like this...

I know there are a lot of samples doing what you are doing on the internet, which doesn't by definition make it a good idea, perhaps consider playing with this wrapper.

```
public interface IFireWallRule :INetFwRule, IDisposable
{

}

class FireWallRule: IFireWallRule
{
    private INetFwRule? _data;
    private bool _disposedValue;

    public FireWallRule(INetFwRule data)
    {
        _data=data;
    }



    internal INetFwRule Root => _data?? throw new ObjectDisposedException("This firewall rule is already disposed and can't be accessed");
    public string Name { get => Root.Name; set => Root.Name=value; }
    public string Description { get => Root.Description; set => Root.Description=value; }
    public string ApplicationName { get => Root.ApplicationName; set => Root.ApplicationName=value; }
    public string serviceName { get => Root.serviceName; set => Root.serviceName=value; }
    public int Protocol { get => Root.Protocol; set => Root.Protocol=value; }
    public string LocalPorts { get => Root.LocalPorts; set => Root.LocalPorts=value; }
    public string RemotePorts { get => Root.RemotePorts; set => Root.RemotePorts=value; }
    public string LocalAddresses { get => Root.LocalAddresses; set => Root.LocalAddresses=value; }
    public string RemoteAddresses { get => Root.RemoteAddresses; set => Root.RemoteAddresses=value; }
    public string IcmpTypesAndCodes { get => Root.IcmpTypesAndCodes; set => Root.IcmpTypesAndCodes=value; }
    public NET_FW_RULE_DIRECTION_ Direction { get => Root.Direction; set => Root.Direction=value; }
    public dynamic Interfaces { get => Root.Interfaces; set => Root.Interfaces=value; }
    public string InterfaceTypes { get => Root.InterfaceTypes; set => Root.InterfaceTypes=value; }
    public bool Enabled { get => Root.Enabled; set => _data.Enabled=value; }
    public string Grouping { get => Root.Grouping; set => _data.Grouping=value; }
    public int Profiles { get => Root.Profiles; set => _data.Profiles=value; }
    public bool EdgeTraversal { get => Root.EdgeTraversal; set => Root.EdgeTraversal=value; }
    public NET_FW_ACTION_ Action { get => Root.Action; set => Root.Action=value; }




    protected virtual void Dispose(bool _)
    {
        if (!_disposedValue)
        {
            if (_data is not null && OperatingSystem.IsWindows())
            {
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(_data);
                _data=null;
            }


            _disposedValue=true;
        }
    }


    ~FireWallRule()
    {
        Dispose(false);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        // Do not change this code. Put cleanup code in 'Dispose(bool disposing)' method
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
}
```

To make life "easy" I'd consider some extension methods to make working with the Wrapper class easier

```
internal static class FireWallExcensionMethods
{
    public static void Add(this INetFwPolicy2 policy, FireWallRule rule)
    {
        policy.Rules.Add(rule.Root);
    }
    public static void Add(this INetFwRules rules, FireWallRule rule)
    {
        rules.Add(rule.Root);
    }
    public static IEnumerable<FireWallRule> GetRules(this INetFwPolicy2 policy)
    {
        foreach (INetFwRule rule in policy.Rules)
        {
            yield return new FireWallRule(rule);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, yes, that SO question got a bit heated. I'll definitely check out your tips as I could 100% use some better troubleshooting in the future. It's been a while now, but I know I threw everything at it that I could find... Dispose, GC.Collect, EntityState (detach, delete), ChangeTracker (disable). Some of those were before I knew where the leak was coming from and was thinking it's SQL... Anyway, if you check my last comment on the question, Microsoft acknowledged it as a bug and slated it for a future fix. Upgrading that firewall app I wrote hasn't been a priority as it works good in 4.x.

Comment: @SumNone, what I like to do, a bit of overkill perhaps is to keep a count of the instances I created and the instances I detected using a static counter that I increment and decrement using interlocked class in the constructor and destructor of the class that I like to inspect, then in my unit test you can call GC.Collect(), do a GC.WaitForFullGCComplete(), the framework should then have called all ~classDisposers and remember to Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(_netFwPolicy); making sure all is written to the firewall. in my .net 6.0 I have no issues with the wrapper pattern